# Get the word around a given position

Tags: python, string

Let

```
s = 'hello you blablablbalba qyosud'
i = 17
```

**How to get the word around position `i`?** i.e. `blablablbalba`  in my example.

---

I was thinking about this, but it seems unpythonic:

```
for j, c in enumerate(s):
    if c == ' ':
        if j < i:
            start = j
        else:
            end = j
            break

print start, end
print s[start+1:end]
```

Comment: how about starting backwards from the i'th element in s; store everything while going backwards until you hit a whitespace; then reverse print the stored string.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the word by space, after that you count the number of the spaces until the threshold parameter (`i`) and this would be the index of the item in the splitted list.

**Solution:**

```
print (s.split()[s[:i].count(" ")])
```

**EDIT:**

If we have more than one space between words and we want to consider two spaces (or more) as one space we can do:

```
print (s.split()[" ".join(s[:i].split()).count(" ")])
```

**Output:**

```
blablablbalba
```

**Explanation:**

This return's 2 as there are two spaces until the 17 index.

```
s[:i].count(" ") # return's 2
```

This return's a list splitted by space.

```
s.split()
```

What you need is the index of the relevant item, which you got from `s[:i].count(" ")`

```
['hello', 'you', 'blablablbalba', 'qyosud']
```

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: @Basj , Thanks :)

Comment: It doesn't work if `s = 'hello you blablablbalba'`. Any idea about a solution that would work in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question,

> p = s[0 : i].rfind(' ')

```
Output: 9
```

For your second question,

> s[ p + 1 : (s[p + 1 : ].find(' ') + p + 1) ]

```
Output: 'blablablbalba'
```

**Description**:

1. Extract the string from the starting to the ith position.
2. Find the index of the last occurrence of space. This will be your starting point for your required word (the second question).
3. Go from here to the next occurrence of space and extract the word in between.

The following consolidated code should work in all scenarios:

```
s = s + ' '
p = s[0 : i].rfind(' ') 
s[ p + 1 : (s[p + 1 : ].find(' ') + p + 1) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple approach with regex,

```
import re
s = 'hello you blablablbalba qyosud'
i = 17
string_at_i = re.findall(r"(\w+)", s[i:])[0]
print(re.findall(r"\w*%s\w*" % string_at_i, s))
```

Updated : Previous pattern was failing when there is space. Current pattern takes care of it !

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(s, i):
    s1 = s[0:i]
    k = s1.rfind(' ')
    pos1 = k
    s1 = s[k+1:len(s)]
    k = s1.find(' ')
    k = s[pos1+1:pos1+k+1]
    return k

s = 'hello you blablablbalba qyosud'
i = 17
k = func(s, i)
print(k)
output:
blablablbalba
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rfind`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) to search for the previous whitespace including `s[i]`:

```
>>> s = 'hello you blablablbalba qyosud'
>>> i = 17
>>> start = s.rfind(' ', 0, i + 1)
>>> start
9
```

Then you can use [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to search the following whitespace again including `s[i]`:

```
>>> end = s.find(' ', i)
>>> end
23
```

And finally use slice to generate the word:

```
>>> s[start+1:(end if end != -1 else None)]
'blablablbalba'
```

Above will result to the word in case `s[i]` is not whitespace. In case `s[i]` is whitespace the result is empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index` or `find` to get the index of the `space` starting from a precise position. In this case it will look for the `space` character position starting from `start+1`. Then, if it finds any space it will print out the word between the two indexes `start` and `end`

```
s = 'hello you blablablbalba qyosud'
def get_word(my_string, start_index):    
    end = -1
    try:
        end = s.find(' ', start_index + 1)
    except ValueError:
        # no second space was found
        pass
    return s[start_index:end] if end else None
print get_word(s)
```

Output: 'blablablbalba'